# Printing Postan POST message

Tags: php, html, post, postman

Goodday,

I am facing a problem fetching send POST messages from postman on my local server. When i send an POST message the postman preview function prints my send data. However the webpage itself doesn't see the data and prints an error.

[Postmand screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DprOm.png)

[Server screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iE6on.png)

Here is my PHP script:

```
<head>
    <title>PHP test page</title>
    <h1>Number</h><br>
</head>

<body>

<?php
    //$i = 0;

    $data = $_POST["par"];
    //while($data == ""){
        //if($i == 0){
        //  echo "No data available";
        //}
        //$i = 1;
    //}
    echo $data;

    //$page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    //$sec = "1";
    //header("Refresh: $sec; url=$page");

?>

</body>
```

I am not experienced with this kind of stuff and am obviously missing something.
Why does the data not appear on the webpage itself?

Greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your webpage, you're probably not sending it as a POST request.

Try debugging:

```
var_dump($_POST);    // Add this. $_POST probably doesn't have an index called "par"
$data = $_POST["par"];
echo $data
```

Comment: Thank you for your response!, this however doens't seem to work either. even with only var_dump($_POST) it shows an empty array.

Comment: Please post your HTML code as well. From what I understand, you probably haven't mentioned any input name as "par".

Comment: The code posted in my origal post is al the code. It is just missing the <!DOCTYPE HTML> and <html></html> tags. But is this code not suppossed to fetch the variable named "par" from an POST message i send via postman?

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work that way. In Postman, you can specify your request type and send data(par, in this case) accordingly. But in real time server, you gotta create a page and send it via post.

Answer (score 0):

You need to POST "par" variable to this page.

Comment: Thank you for your response!, I do POST the variable "par" with a value via postman. or is there an different way to do this?

Comment: Yes, post man is tool which send post request to your file and show you the response.  You have to create another file with form that will send par variable to your file.